# Am I using the correct syntax for my shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a shell script that gets a value from a file and based on that value I want to echo a particular message. My console keeps on saying that there is an error on line 7 and 9. Any suggestions on how to fix it will be greatly appreciated.

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home'
echo $JAVA_HOME
export CLASSPATH='/Users/edgarjohnson/Desktop/JarFiles/mlDownload.jar:/ddc/config'
echo $CLASSPATH
var=$(cat /ddc/config/LastRefreshDate.dat)
echo $var
if [$var > 0 ];then
        echo "Run Get Latest Update Class"
elif [$var = 0]; then
        echo "No need to run any updates"
fi
```

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `[` and before `]` there must be a space. Otherwise the variable is substituted and the shell will try to execute a program called `[Whatever`.

`[` itself is actually just a binary which is executed with `var`'s content, `=`, `0` and `]` as arguments and its return code is used to determine whether the `if` or `else` branch should be taken.

However the operators used are not really the ones you intend to use, e.g. `>` is interpreted as shell redirect creating a file called `0` (or overwritting it) and is not actually comparing anything, use `-gt` instead. `=` checks string equality, `-eq` checks value equality.

As mentioned in the comments it may be better to use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: Worked like a charm Thanks

Comment: Not quite.  `>` is not an argument passed to `[`.  `>` is a redirection operator, so  `[$var > 0 ]` attempts to run the program identified by the string `[$var` with its output going to a newly created file named `0`.

Comment: Actually, you should use [[...]] which avoid the variable expansion and lower the need for quoting. Also, since it's a numerical comparison, it should be [[ $var -gt 0 ]] and [[ $var -eq 0 ]].

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have fixed that mistake

Comment: I recommend reading the bash manual too, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html.  I know there's a lot there, but that is the best source for writing shell scripts.

Comment: Note that there is some dispute about `[[` vs `[`.  Personally, I prefer neither, and use `[` spelled `test`.  The problem with `[[` is that it does not generate useful error messages.  If you try to do a numeric comparison with a string, for example.  `[[ foo > 0 ]]` does not generate an error message, but `[ foo -gt 0 ]` does.  Most people, however, seem to prefer `[[` despite this limitation.